# Adding dropdown menu in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

How do i add a dropdown menu for both of the icon classes? E.g of drop down menu would be like register, login, track order, wishlist etc. This is my nav bar menu with no dropdown/sublist. Can i see an example for both CSS and HTML?

```html
<ul id="nav-main">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-item1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about" class="nav-item2">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/faq" class="nav-item3">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Contact" class="nav-item4">Contact</a></li>
        <li>
            <form action="action_page.php">
                <input type="search" name="savanasearch" placeholder="Search..."
                       class="nav-item5">
            </form>
        </li>
        <li style="float:right">
            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">account_circle</i></a>
        </li>
        <li style="float:right">
            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Do you need a drop down menu code? Or you want to convert your this menu to drop down menu?

Comment: i need the drop down menu code

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag `javascript`, but it's quite difficult to do this without js. However, there are some cheats to display a dropdown menu when you hover over an element, but it doesn't work with clicks:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
#content {
  padding: 40px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#nav-main {
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 7px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #4488dd;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#nav-main li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 7px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 36px;
  transition: .1s;
}
#nav-main li:hover {
  background-color: #3366aa;
}
#nav-main li > a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav-main li input[type=search] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 0 3px;
  line-height: 22px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
#nav-main li:hover input[type=search] {
  opacity: 1;
}

#nav-main li .dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4488dd;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -7px;
  line-height: 26px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
/* Here comes the clue: */
#nav-main li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
#nav-main .dropdown ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav-main .dropdown ul li {
  float: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 -7px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav-main">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item1">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about" class="nav-item2">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/faq" class="nav-item3">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Contact" class="nav-item4">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
        <form action="action_page.php">
            <input type="search" name="savanasearch" placeholder="Search..."
                   class="nav-item5">
        </form>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right">
        <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">account_circle</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          Dropdown 2
          <ul>
            <li>Hi!</li>
            <li>Hi!</li>
            <li>Hi!</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right">
        <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          Dropdown 1
          <ul>
            <li>Hi!</li>
            <li>Hi!</li>
            <li>Hi!</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad prompta invenire dissentiunt quo, dignissim assentior efficiendi quo ei. Mea audiam lobortis sententiae no, vix ornatus labores qualisque ne. Usu adolescens voluptaria id, quo at habemus invenire. Sententiae philosophia vis in, id incorrupte dissentias mel. Ut brute disputationi pro, no malis eirmod has. Pri debitis insolens in, cu eirmod maluisset scriptorem sit.</p>

<p>At fugit ludus qui, et sit dictas adolescens. Agam habemus usu ne. Eum duis mollis torquatos no, usu atomorum voluptaria incorrupte ex. Usu no latine vocibus nusquam, ea sea dictas diceret philosophia. Deleniti probatus cum et, corpora noluisse abhorreant no eum.</p>

<p>Placerat vituperatoribus an mei. Cu hinc atqui civibus mei. Per ne aliquid postulant. Qui no persius referrentur, doming facilis te nam.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your drop down menu code :-

```css
.mainmenu{
    list-style: none;
    width: available;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    overflow: visible;
}

  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
  
  ul li {
    width: 175px;  
    display: block; 
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
  
  li ul {
    display: none;margin-left: 0px;
}
  ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
}
  ul li a:hover {
    background: #f00;
  }
  li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  }
  li:hover li {
    float: none;
  }
  li:hover a {
      background: #f00;
  }
  li:hover li a:hover {
      background: #000;
  }
  #drop-nav li ul li {
      border-top: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="drop-nav" class="mainmenu">
                    <li><a href="#">My Menu</a>
                        <ul id="nav-main">
                            <li><a href="#" class="nav-item1">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/about" class="nav-item2">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/faq" class="nav-item3">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Contact" class="nav-item4">Contact</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <form action="action_page.php">
                                    <input type="search" name="savanasearch" placeholder="Search..." class="nav-item5">
                                </form>
                            </li>
                            <li style="float:right">
                                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">account_circle</i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="float:right">
                                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    
 </ul>
```

Hope it will help.